# RavenDb Inserts don't appear straight away

Tags: ravendb

One page users fill in a form which creates a record in raven db. Then they are directed to a list page which shows all their records.

The new item does not instantly appear on the list page. Although pressing F5 to do a refresh causes it to appear.

Is there an issue with raven here or is it likely something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the way ravendb is designed, what you are seeing here is a stale index. When you insert new documents, any index relating to this document needs to catch up, at this point the index is classed as stale.

You can read more on the ravendb website, or a quick google should give you plenty to read.

Comment: that's cool, in fact i thought I did read about it somewhere. what strategies can be used to improve user experience?

Comment: @Nick Some ideas: It's possible to find out if an index is stale ([see here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes)). Then you can (a) tell the user that their results may change if they run their search in a few seconds/minutes, (b) wait to perform the search until the index becomes non-stale (probably not ideal), or (c) show the stale results, behind the scenes run the search once the index becomes non-stale, then automatically display any new results found.